# Error while installing ambari-metrics-monitor HDP 2.3

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I am trying to install ambari-metrics-monitor on a node using Ambari 2.1.1 for HDP 2.3 but getting following error

```
Starting ambari-metrics-monitor
Verifying ambari-metrics-monitor process status...
ERROR: ambari-metrics-monitor start failed. For more details, see /data/log/ambari-metrics-monitor/ambari-metrics-monitor.out:
====================
    from core.controller import Controller
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_monitoring/core/controller.py", line 28, in <module>
    from metric_collector import MetricsCollector
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_monitoring/core/metric_collector.py", line 23, in <module>
    from host_info import HostInfo
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_monitoring/core/host_info.py", line 22, in <module>
    import psutil
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_monitoring/psutil/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/psutil/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from psutil._common import memoize
ImportError: No module named _common
```

any suggestions/help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply did a manual build for the ambari agents by running
./build in the installation directory of the ambari agents and then started it manually it worked for me

Answer (score -1):

Could you please check status of the ambari-agent on that node.if it is already running restart the ambari-agent and try to start again.